# Lambda not rendering in MDPI Journal

Tags: rendering

Why the lambda is not rendering in equation (2) below? What was my mistake there? You will need the Definitions folder from the MDPI journal template to run this.

```
\documentclass[energies,article,submit,pdftex,moreauthors]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test_lambda}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Like this, it works:

\begin{equation}
    \lambda
\end{equation}

But here, it does not work:

\begin{equation}
        \mathbf{w_{out} = r^{\mathit{T}}M(M^{\mathit{T}}M + \mathit{\lambda}^{\mathrm{2}}I)^{-1}},
\end{equation}

And like this $\lambda$, it also works.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**: Link to get the MDPI template:

[Template](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex)

Comment: Use `\lambda` without the mathit ?

Comment: @Rmano Already tried that, unfortunately it does not change anything.

Comment: Can you share a link to where we can get the class from?

Comment: it should also be outside of `\mathbf`. It is better to only include the characters that you actually want to put in bold or italic, like `\mathbf{w_{out}} = \mathbf{r}^{T}\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{M}^{T}\mathbf{M} + \lambda^{2}\mathbf{I})^{-1}`.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz added the link to template.

Comment: @Marijn oh, yes, you are correct. You can put that as answer, it solved my problem.

Comment: surely you got an error from `\title{test_lambda}`  ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no, not really. That piece of code throws a lot of errors, but none related to `\title{test_lamba}`. I can even remove that command line and nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font does not include a bold math version of lambda. If you can live with a normal math lambda, you could use `\mathnormal` to switch back to the normal weight:

```
\documentclass[energies,article,submit,pdftex,moreauthors]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
\pubyear{2023}
\copyrightyear{2023}
%\externaleditor{Academic Editor: Firstname Lastname}
\datereceived{ } 
\daterevised{ } % Comment out if no revised date
\dateaccepted{ } 
\datepublished{ } 
%\datecorrected{} % For corrected papers: "Corrected: XXX" date in the original paper.
%\dateretracted{} % For corrected papers: "Retracted: XXX" date in the original paper.
\hreflink{https://doi.org/} % If needed use \linebreak
\Title{Title}

% MDPI internal command: Title for citation in the left column
\TitleCitation{Title}

% Author Orchid ID: enter ID or remove command
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidA{} behind the author's name
%\newcommand{\orcidauthorB}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidB{} behind the author's name

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{Firstname Lastname $^{1,\dagger,\ddagger}$\orcidA{}, Firstname Lastname $^{2,\ddagger}$ and Firstname Lastname $^{2,}$*}

%\longauthorlist{yes}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname and Firstname Lastname}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for citation in the left column
\AuthorCitation{Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.}
% If this is a Chicago style journal: Lastname, Firstname, Firstname Lastname, and Firstname Lastname.

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
$^{1}$ \quad Affiliation 1; e-mail@e-mail.com\\
$^{2}$ \quad Affiliation 2; e-mail@e-mail.com}

% Contact information of the corresponding author
\corres{Correspondence: e-mail@e-mail.com; Tel.: (optional; include country code; if there are multiple corresponding authors, add author initials) +xx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx (F.L.)}

% Current address and/or shared authorship
\firstnote{Current address: Affiliation 3.} 
\secondnote{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Like this, it works:

\begin{equation}
    \lambda
\end{equation}

But here, it does not work:

\begin{equation}
        \mathbf{w_{out} = r^{\mathit{T}}M(M^{\mathit{T}}M + \mathnormal{\lambda}^{\mathrm{2}}I)^{-1}},
\end{equation}

And like this $\lambda$, it also works.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The culprit is `\usepackage{mathpazo}` (you can reproduce the problem with `article` if you load it)